# How do I encode my label from a CSV dataframe that points into a ungrouped video dataset

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I have a dataset of videos, each video has a unique name. attached to this dataset is a CSV file,it contains the unique ID and the corresponding label. some videos have the same label but no video have the same ID. I have to Preprocess this videos into suitable frames and then feed them into my model for action identification, however I run into series of problems trying to encode my labels.

```
class FrameGenerator:
    def __init__(self, df, training=False):
        """
        Returns a set of frames with their associated labels.

        Args:
            path: Video file paths.
            n_frames: Number of frames.
            dataframe: DataFrame containing class labels.
            class_column: Name of the DataFrame column with class labels.
            training: Boolean to determine if the training dataset is being created.
        """
        self.class_names = sorted(set(df['text']))
        self.class_ids_for_name = dict((name, idx) for idx, name in enumerate(self.class_names))
        self.dataframe = df

    def __call__(self):
        video_paths, classes, start, end = self.get_files_and_class_names()

        pairs = list(zip(video_paths, classes, start, end))

        for path, name, start_frame, end_frame in pairs:
            video_frames = capture_video_sequences(path, start_frame , end_frame)
            label =  self.class_ids_for_name[name.to_string(index=False)]  # Encode labels
            yield video_frames, label

fg = FrameGenerator(df)
seed_everything(42)
data = []
labels = []
for frames, label in fg():
    data.append(frames)
    labels.append(label)
```

### here is my last attempt, and I run into an error like this

```
---> 36     label =  self.class_ids_for_name[name.to_string(index=False)]  # Encode labels


KeyError: '                           Ё\n                      курица\n ......
```